# Update column with output of select within the same table in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, sql-update

I have a table with a start and end time like so

```
stime | etime

12:00  |  13:20
```

i now have to add a third column with the duration

```
stime  |  etime  | durationMins

12:00  |  13:20   |  80
```

I have this to get my duration in minutes

```
 SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(stime , etime))/60  AS MinuteDiff 
 FROM mytable
```

MinuteDiff now contains my minutes, how can I update durationMins for all rows based on the above select?

Comment: You wouldn't normally store derived data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have the durationMins column already created

```
 UPDATE Table_name
 set durationMins = TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(stime , etime))/60  AS MinuteDiff
```

This should work.

Comment: works thanks although the AS minuteDiff is not needed